# Moving Ubuntu from one computer to another

Tags: 12.10, wubi

i have my laptop pc with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.10 as secondary OS. I was using wubi installer to create ext4 partitions for ubuntu in the same partition as Windows. I have a lot of complicated software installed on ubuntu (it would take a lot of time to install everything again on a fresh ubuntu) and i would like to move that Ubuntu ext4 partition to my new PC which also has Windows 7 and make it bootable.

Is it possible to move that partition and keep all the software intact and make it bootable and what would be possible steps how to do this?
Maybe someone could point me to some kind of tutorial for such a task?

Comment: Here's what google suggests: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MigrateWubi. It's https://www.google.com/.

Comment: It seems to be what i was looking for. Your google skills are better than mine :)

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted an alternate solution to using the script provided in the comments, remastersys might be a good option. Wubi installs are small (remastersys won't work if the image it creates is more than 4gb). I'd install remastersys as per the instructions on their webpage in the wubi install. I would however change the working directory to somewhere on a larger partition, such as your windows partition

To do that select customise

[image]

then configure

[image]

then change the workdir

[image]

Once thats done go back to the main screen and hit backup - this will generate an ISO in your workdir. Burn or use wubi to boot, then install as per normal

Comment: Remastersys seems like a nice tool, but in my case ubuntu with all software consumes more than 4GB of space...